# company-clang is slow under Cocoa Emacs

Tags: macos, emacs, autocomplete, company-mode

I'm using the GUI version emacs on Mac.

I set `company-idle-delay` to `0`, but emacs also delay several seconds when completes with company-clang.

But, when I start emacs in terminal, company completes very fast. What is the differents between GUI / terminal emacs?

I installed emacs with `brew install emacs --with-cocoa`, version 24.5